# Incompatibility between apostrophe ’ and utf8

Tags: input-encodings, apostrophe

The code below only works without the `utf8` option of the `inputenc` package or by removing the apostrophe from `M’` and `N’`,

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,tkz-base}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\tkzInit[ymin=-3]
\tkzClip[space=1]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(8,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(3.5,10){I}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto A--B](I) \tkzGetPoint{J}
\tkzInterLC(I,A)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{M’}{M}
\tkzInterLC(I,B)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{N}{N’}
\tkzDrawCircle[diameter](A,B)
\tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
\tkzMarkRightAngles(A,M,B A,N,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[style=dashed,color=blue](I,J)
\tkzShowTransformation[projection=onto A--B,color=red,size=3,gap=-3](I)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=red](M,N)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=blue](O,A,B,I)
\tkzLabelPoints(O) \tkzLabelPoints[above right](N,I)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](M,A)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Error message

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,A)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{M’}{M}
Extra \endcsname. \tkzInterLC(I,A)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{M’}{M}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,A)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{M’}{M}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,A)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{M’}{M}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,A)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{M’}{M}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,A)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{M’}{M}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,A)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{M’}{M}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,B)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{N}{N’}
Extra \endcsname. \tkzInterLC(I,B)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{N}{N’}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,B)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{N}{N’}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,B)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{N}{N’}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,B)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{N}{N’}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,B)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{N}{N’}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \tkzInterLC(I,B)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{N}{N’}
Use of \pgf@sh@ma@N doesn't match its definition. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Extra \endcsname. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Use of \pgf@sh@ns@N doesn't match its definition. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `center' (in 'center'). \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Use of \pgf@sh@ns@N doesn't match its definition. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Use of \pgf@sh@nt@N doesn't match its definition. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Argument of \xcolor@ has an extra }. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Paragraph ended before \xcolor@ was complete. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Argument of \@next has an extra }. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Paragraph ended before \@next was complete. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Missing } inserted. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Missing } inserted. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Missing $ inserted. \tkzDrawSegments(I,A I,B A,B B,M A,N)
Use of \pgf@sh@ma@N doesn't match its definition. \tkzMarkRightAngles(A,M,B A,N,B)
Extra \endcsname. \tkzMarkRightAngles(A,M,B A,N,B)
Use of \pgf@sh@ns@N doesn't match its definition. \tkzMarkRightAngles(A,M,B A,N,B)
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `center' (in 'center'). \tkzMarkRightAngles(A,M,B A,N,B)
Use of \pgf@sh@ns@N doesn't match its definition. \tkzMarkRightAngles(A,M,B A,N,B)
Use of \pgf@sh@nt@N doesn't match its definition. \tkzMarkRightAngles(A,M,B A,N,B)
Argument of \xcolor@ has an extra }. \tkzMarkRightAngles(A,M,B A,N,B)
Paragraph ended before \xcolor@ was complete. \tkzMarkRightAngles(A,M,B A,N,B)
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 22.
```

Comment: Use `M'` (with the ASCII apostrophe).

Comment: For example, there is a command from the tkz-euclide package, \ tkzDefPointsBy [<local options>] ( 〈 liste de pts 〉 ){ 〈 liste de pts 〉 }, which automatically generates the second list by adding apostroph to the points in the first list. Besides other situations that would be useful for me to solve this problem

Comment: Unfortunately, when you copy-paste from a PDF you often get the wrong character in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It often happens that copying code from a PDF file leads to incorrect TeX markup.

For instance, if I copy the code on page 40 of the manual for `tkz-euclide` (version 1.16c) and paste it here, I get

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(2,-1){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(2,2){B}
  \tkzDefPointsBy[symmetry=center O](B,A){}
  \tkzDrawLine(A,A’)
  \tkzDrawLine(B,B’)
  \tkzMarkAngle[mark=s,arc=lll,size=2 cm,mkcolor=red](A,O,B)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1,circle,draw,fill=blue!10](A,O,B){$60^{\circ}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is invalid code, unfortunately: the font tries to be smart and advertises the apostrophe to be U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, whereas the code intended it to be U+0027 APOSTROPHE.

There’s not much you can do, unfortunately, except replacing `’` with `'`. The valid code is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(2,-1){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(2,2){B}
  \tkzDefPointsBy[symmetry=center O](B,A){}
  \tkzDrawLine(A,A')
  \tkzDrawLine(B,B')
  \tkzMarkAngle[mark=s,arc=lll,size=2 cm,mkcolor=red](A,O,B)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1,circle,draw,fill=blue!10](A,O,B){$60^{\circ}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Your example features the very same problem.

Comment: I understand. It is that in the tkz-euclide manual the author uses utf8 and the examples codes appear with `’`, I was in doubt if it would be working with `’`. In pgmanual also appears `’` used to reverse the position of the label

Comment: @MarceloRodrigues It does not depend on the encoding of the input, but only on PDF properties. The apostrophe in the manual of PGF falls into the same case.